# xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xctest", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xctest, xcode-command-line-tools

I am using Xcode command line tools instead of XCode app in my MAC. 
When i use `swift --version`
I get `Apple Swift version 5.2.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.6 clang-1103.0.32.51)`
I cloned a project with

```
git clone https://github.com/apple/example-package-dealer.git
cd example-package-dealer
swift run Dealer
```

I gives me this error:

```
error: terminated(72): OLDPWD=/Users/sayansen/Work/EdgeAnalytics/Trial TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal PWD=/Users/sayansen/Work/EdgeAnalytics/Trial/example-package-dealer SHLVL=1 SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.9lwBmlYTAx/Listeners HOME=/Users/sayansen LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0 XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0 TMPDIR=/var/folders/kn/v4zm474x52n8zrycxs7nh5c40000gn/T/ LOGNAME=sayansen SHELL=/bin/bash TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=433 _=/usr/bin/swift PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS CPATH=/usr/local/include SDKROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk XPC_FLAGS=0x0 TERM=xterm-256color USER=sayansen LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 TERM_SESSION_ID=B285E686-2802-48C6-B8CE-03CA8F2314BF xcrun --sdk macosx --find xctest output:
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xctest", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

**I am not using XCODE.**
I already did this:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

But not helpfull.

How to solve this error without installing XCode?

Comment: I found xctest here : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xctest, seems you have to install XCode to have it.

Comment: @Philippe oh so no other way? I was avoiding installing xcode

Comment: Looks like it's you specified just not an appropriate path with `-s`, should be `-s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and that's it.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Assuming you already have Xcode installed:

Start Xcode, select "Preferences -> Locations". Chances are that your Command Line Tools are not set. Select the suggested Xcode-tools location and you are done.

Additional:

You could check with:

```
xcode-select -p
```

which tools are set, mine showed:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

After the location in the preferences was set, it showed:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

(as it should)

Comment: Although the accepted answer, it does not address the original constraint, being: "How to solve this error without installing XCode?". To answer that question, it is currently not possible to build/run/test SPM packages using only the Command Line Tools.

Comment: @JeremyWiebe that's the common thing with SO.

Comment: The actual answer is given by @mojtaba-hosseini

Comment: No, none of the answers given in this thread actually answered OP's question. They asked how to solve the problem without installing XCode. AFAIK, there's no way to build/run/test programs on MacOS without installing XCode.

Answer (score 73):

Xcode -> Preferences (or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)

[image: Preview]

Locations tab -> Command Line tools section:
Select a tool there and you are done.

Comment: this is the answer.

Comment: The original question asked how to achieve this without using Xcode

Answer (score 10):

Just a wrong path, all the stuff still can be done w/o invoking GUI:

```
~/% sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
~/% sudo xcode-select -p                                    
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
~/% sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
~/% sudo xcode-select -p                                           
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

The latest `-s` command fixes `xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xctest" …`

Comment: Thanks. Running `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` fixed the problem.

Comment: Fixed my problem for building Unreal Engine - Fail to generate Xcode project with GenerateProjectFiles, WARNING: Exception while generating include data for UnrealEditor: Platform Mac is not a valid platform to build. Check that the SDK is installed properly.